# Dynamic and Static Scoping

Tags: scope

Me and my friend are having some trouble in regards to understanding Static and Dynamic scoping. I believe with dynamic, the variable (global) will keep being updated by other functions until printed, whereas with static I think that whatever value get's assigned to a variable first stays that way.

Is this thinking correct or no?

For an example using my thoughts above I have calculated the following from this code snippet.

```
int a, b, c;
void p() {
    int a = 3;
    b = 1;
    c = a + b;
    q();
}
void print() { printf(“%d %d %d\n”, a, b, c); }

void q() {
    int b = 4;
    a = 5;
    c = a + b;
    print();
}
main() {
    int c = 5; 
    p();
} 
Output with static scoping: 315
Output with dynamic scoping: 549
```

Comment: What language is this about? Please add the proper tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With static scoping, `print` would fail because neither `a`, `b`, nor `c` are assigned values either inside `print` or at the scope where `print` is *defined* (namely, the first line of the file).

With dynamic scoping, the output would be 549, since each of `a`, `b`, and `c` has a value assigned in `q`. Not demonstrated by your code is also the fact that after `q` returns from its call inside `p`, the *local* variable `a` has the value 5 set in `q`, not the global variable. Namely, the following occurs:

1. Global variables `a`, `b`, and `c` are declared, but do not have values. Let's assume your language initializes such values to 0.
2. `main` is called. A variable `c` local to `main` is given the value `5`; global `c` still equals 0.
3. `p` is called. A `p`-local variable `a` is assigned the value 3; global `a` is still 0.
4. No local variable `b` exists in `p` or its caller, `main`, so the global `b` is set to 1.
5. No local variable `c` exists in `p`, but one does in `c`, to its value is set to 3 + 1  = 4.
6. `q` is called. A local `b` is declared and set to 4, leaving global `b` set to 0.
7. No local variable `a` exists in `q`, but one does in its caller `p`, so that value changes from 3 to 5.
8. No local variable `c` exists in `q` or its caller `p`, but does in `p`'s caller `main`, so that value is set to 5 + 4 = 9. Global `c` is still 0.
9. `print` is called, and lacking any local `a`, `b`, or `c`, it looks back in its call chain. It uses `a` from `p`, `b` from `q`, and `c` from `main` (none of the globals are used.
10. `q` returns. In `p`, the values of `a` and `c` are still 5 and 9 as set in `q`. `b` is still 1, since `q` declared a local `b`.
11. `p` returns. In `main`, we still have `a=0` (since `p` declared its own copy before calling `q`), `b=1` (since `p` modified the global `b`), and `c=9` (since `q` ultimately modified the variable local to `c`).
12. `main` returns. We still have global `a=0`, `b=1`, and `c=0`.

If that's confusing (and I didn't confuse myself and make any mistakes), you might understand why most languages use static scoping: it's not only much easier, but possible, to reason about the behavior of the program without having to run or simulate it just to track variable assignments.

Comment: No. The very *definition* of static scoping is that you can determine which variables are used *before* (or *without*) running the program. Static scoping is also known as lexical scoping, since variable scopes can be resolved using only the text of the program, without needing to know the control flow. Put another way, `a` et al. in `print` always refer to the 3 global variables, regardless of what variables might exist in the local frame of whoever *calls* `print`.

Comment: If your code snippet is C, then under static typing (which C uses) the 'print' routine prints the current values of the global/file level variables a, b, and c (declared on line #1).  It does not 'fail' - it has a well defined behavior.

Comment: "Fail" was a poor choice of word. More accurate to say that the output is undefined (or rather, language-dependent) since none of the globals is assigned a value.

Answer (score 0):

static scoping-  5 1 9// it takes global values as variables not defined within print function

dynamic scoping- 5 4 9